# Mysql slowness in query execution

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I am loading data into Mysql DB(8.0.16) through pentaho(8.3) jobs, from the last 2months process was going fine(jobs usually complete in 1hr), Since last night the process is going very slow(executing for more than 12hrs), I have checked the processlist the queries are taking for ever for executing(even the count on small volume tables). am unable to figureout the issue.
any suggestions to findout the bottlenecks.

Comment: Your MySQL might have become unresponsive. Do you have a backup? If so, it would make sense to import the backup on another similar machine and run the same Pentaho thing there. If in an hour it's executed, then it's something with your RDBMS process. If not, then it's something with your data.

Comment: if you added index please disabled index first then start loading data.

Comment: Thank you Lajos.. There is a backup process executing on MySQL, but after long deliberation MySQL was restarted and the process became normal..